# Ubuntu 15.10: share internet connection over WiFi

Tags: networking, wireless, reverse-tethering

Having two WiFi interfaces I'd like to use one as a hotspot, but the simple instructions found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-adhoc.html) don't work, no new wireless network is detected by any device (neither Android nor Windows PC).

Any clue? Are in Ubuntu 15.10 still required additional softwares as suggested by some answers to [similar questions](https://askubuntu.com/q/399496/166416) regarding older Ubuntu version? If so, which one should be used with Ubuntu 15.10?

Comment: still having the same problem?

Comment: @Nuwan I gave up and later I passed to Lubuntu 16.04, but did not try anymore this feature.